# Issue with leaderboards

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a leaderboard for some time things in discord.py. Ive made a command that changes the leaderboard so I don't have to replace the embed. Since it looks if the time is faster than other times on the leaderboard its an int and there can't be dots, comma's or : in the int. I'm trying to get times on the leaderboard like this: 00:13:64. But I need to put a negative sign infront of the time if I want the code to work. Can anybody help me with how I can fix this in like maybe let the code remove the negative sign when it prints it into the embed?
Edit: with the negative sign the time would look like this: -00:13:64

Answer (score 0):

```
str("-00:13:64")[1:]
```

What did you mean? I'm not sure. Is that data save by str? If it's int, you can convert int to str and replace "-" to "".

Comment: well like this is the code: https://pastebin.com/Jueuj7Ek so like the person does the command "-modify machloop {tag} {what} in discord. and the tag is the name of the person and the what is the time.